# After upgrading the App to iOS 9 the vertical lines of table view is not displaying

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am working on upgrading the App to iOS 9 from version iOS 8. When i executes the code after all the changes the vertical lines of the table view is not displaying for some columns. So when i searched this i got a solution to add the following line.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
    return 61.0f;
}
```

But still its not working. Its not displaying the vertical margins. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.